# Already defined in dllmain.obj

Tags: c++

I'm trying to clean a bit my code moving some parts to they .h and .cpp files.

The problem is that when I try to compile, I get a "already defined" error.

I know there are several questions like this one. But I've checked several times and I don't see any duplicated definition, also can't see anything outside it's place. Can't detect where is the problem...

It's a dll code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "includes.h"

DWORD WINAPI HackThread(HMODULE hModule)
{
    //find_main_window(GetCurrentProcessId());
    InitFunctions();

    AllocConsole();
    FILE* f;
    freopen_s(&f, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);       
    
    // init modules
    std::cout << "moduleBase: " << std::hex << moduleBase << std::endl;
    uintptr_t map = (uintptr_t)((moduleBase + dwMap));    
    std::cout << "map: " << map << std::endl;
    uintptr_t protocolGame = (uintptr_t)((moduleBase + m_protocolGame));
    std::cout << "protocolGame: " << protocolGame << std::endl;

    // offsets
    constexpr ptrdiff_t offset_itemId = 0x2C;
    constexpr ptrdiff_t offset_itemCount = 0x30;    

    // get localplayer
    DWORD LocalPlayerPointer = (DWORD)((moduleBase + dwLocalPlayer));        
    DWORD LocalPlayerAddress = *(DWORD*)LocalPlayerPointer;
    // enable after testing when moving to loop: if (LocalPlayer == 0 || LocalPlayerPointer == 0) continue;
    std::cout << "LocalPlayerPointer: " << LocalPlayerPointer << std::endl;
    std::cout << "LocalPlayerAddress: " << LocalPlayerAddress << std::endl;

    // wait for activate
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END))
    {
        Sleep(10);
    }
    //system("cls");

    // read inventory
    for (int i = 0; i <= Const::InventorySlot::LastInventorySlot; i++) {
        DWORD buffer = 0, itemId = 0, itemCount = 0;
        getInventoryItem(LocalPlayerAddress, &buffer, i);
        if (buffer != 0) {
            itemId = *(DWORD*)(buffer + offset_itemId);
            itemCount = *(DWORD*)(buffer + offset_itemCount);
        }
        if (itemId != 0) {
            std::cout << "Item" << i << ": " << std::hex << buffer << std::endl;
            std::cout << "ID: " << std::dec << itemId << " x" << itemCount << std::endl;
        }
    }    

    // get tiles
    TileList tiles;
    getTiles(map, &tiles, 7);
    for (TilePtr tile : tiles) {
        DWORD buffer;
        // getTopCreature
        getTopCreature(tile, &buffer);
        // check if creature isLocalPlayer
        if (buffer != 0 && buffer != LocalPlayerAddress) {
            std::cout << "buffer: " << std::hex << buffer << std::endl;
            // findItemInContainers
            DWORD item = 0;
            uintptr_t itemid = 3198; //hmm
            findItemInContainers(LocalPlayerPointer, &item, itemid, 1);
            if (item != 0) {
                std::cout << "Item " << std::dec << itemid << " found: " << std::hex << item << std::endl;
                std::cout << "(DWORD*)&tile: " << (DWORD*)&tile << std::endl;
                std::cout << "&tile: " << &tile << std::endl;
                std::cout << "*tile: " << *tile << std::endl;
                std::cout << "tile: " << tile << std::endl;
                // shoot
                useWith(LocalPlayerPointer, &item, (DWORD*)&tile, 0); // ERROR IS HERE IN PARAMETER (DWORD*)&tile
                                                                      // the game will try to call [(DWORD*)&tile + 0x20] then break
                break;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Item " << itemid << " not found: " << std::dec << itemid << std::endl;
            }
        }            
    }        

    std::cout << "sleeping 3 seconds" << std::endl;
    Sleep(3000);
    std::cout << "ready" << std::endl;

    // wait for activate
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END))
    {
        Sleep(10);
    }

    // stop follow
    cancelFollow(LocalPlayerPointer);
    std::cout << "Stopped follow" << std::endl;    

    // sendinput
    /*
    SendMsg(WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F1);
    SendMsg(WM_KEYUP, VK_F1);
    */

    // wait for END then detach
    std::cout << "Press ESC to remove hook" << std::endl;
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
    {
      // aimbot        
        // get target
        DWORD attacking = isAttacking(LocalPlayerPointer);

        // get who is attacking X
        /*DWORD buffer;
        getAttackingCreature(LocalPlayer, &buffer);
        std::cout << "buffer: " << buffer << std::endl;*/                    

      // manatrainer        
        double mana = getMana(LocalPlayerAddress);
        std::cout << "Mana: " << std::dec << mana << std::endl;
        if (mana > MANA_TO_RUNE) {
            talkChannel(LocalPlayerPointer, 1, 0, SPELL_TO_USE);
            Sleep(3000);
            // useItem
            DWORD buffer = 0, itemId = 0, itemCount = 0;
            getInventoryItem(LocalPlayerAddress, &buffer, Const::InventorySlot::InventorySlotAmmo);
            if (buffer != 0) {
                std::cout << "sending useItem()" << std::endl;
                itemId = *(DWORD*)(buffer + offset_itemId);
                itemCount = *(DWORD*)(buffer + offset_itemCount);
                useItem(LocalPlayerPointer, &buffer);
            }
        }         

        Sleep(10);
    }

    fclose(f);
    FreeConsole();
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hModule, 0);
    return 0;
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        CloseHandle(CreateThread(nullptr, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)HackThread, hModule, 0, nullptr));
    }
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

The includes.h looks like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "constants.h"
#include <vector>
#include <list>
//#include "stdext/shared_object.h"
//#include "inputs.h"
#include "declarations.h"
#include "functions.h"
#include "offsets.h"
```

Functions.h

```
#pragma once
#include "includes.h"

void InitFunctions();

uintptr_t moduleBase;

// getMana
typedef double(__thiscall* _getMana)(DWORD localplayer);
_getMana getMana;
// isAttacking
typedef int(__thiscall* _isAttacking)(DWORD localplayer);
_isAttacking isAttacking;
// getInventoryItem
typedef DWORD(__thiscall* _getInventoryItem)(DWORD localplayer, DWORD* buffer, uintptr_t index);
_getInventoryItem getInventoryItem;
// cancelFollow
typedef DWORD(__thiscall* _cancelFollow)(DWORD localplayer);
_cancelFollow cancelFollow;
// findItemInContainers
typedef DWORD(__thiscall* _findItemInContainers)(DWORD localplayer, DWORD* buffer, uintptr_t id, uintptr_t type);
_findItemInContainers findItemInContainers;
// talkChannel
typedef DWORD(__thiscall* _talkChannel)(DWORD localplayer, uintptr_t mode, uintptr_t channelId, const std::string& message);
_talkChannel talkChannel;
// useWith
typedef void(__thiscall* _useWith)(DWORD localplayer, DWORD* item, DWORD* toThing, uintptr_t subType);
_useWith useWith;
// getAttackingCreature
typedef DWORD(__thiscall* _getAttackingCreature)(DWORD localplayer, DWORD* buffer);
_getAttackingCreature getAttackingCreature;
// useItem    
typedef void(__thiscall* _useItem)(DWORD localplayer, DWORD* item);
_useItem useItem;
// get tiles
typedef void(__thiscall* _getTiles)(DWORD map, TileList* buffer, uintptr_t floor);
_getTiles getTiles;
// getTopCreature
typedef void(__thiscall* _getTopCreature)(TilePtr tile, DWORD* buffer);
_getTopCreature getTopCreature;
```

And functions.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "includes.h"

void InitFunctions(){
    // get base address
    moduleBase = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(L"NewHorizon_DirectX.exe");
    _getMana getMana;
    getMana = (_getMana)(moduleBase + 0x5A830);
    isAttacking = (_isAttacking)(moduleBase + 0x734A0);
    getInventoryItem = (_getInventoryItem)(moduleBase + 0x949C0);
    cancelFollow = (_cancelFollow)(moduleBase + 0x73420);
    findItemInContainers = (_findItemInContainers)(moduleBase + 0x78710);
    talkChannel = (_talkChannel)(moduleBase + 0x79340);
    useWith = (_useWith)(moduleBase + 0x78220);
    getAttackingCreature = (_getAttackingCreature)(moduleBase + 0x93F90);
    useItem = (_useItem)(moduleBase + 0x77E60);
    getTiles = (_getTiles)(moduleBase + 0x142860);
    getTopCreature = (_getTopCreature)(moduleBase + 0x192BC0);
}
```

When I try to compile, I get this errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "unsigned int moduleBase" (?moduleBase@@3IA) already defined in dllmain.obj Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "double (__thiscall* getMana)(unsigned long)" (?getMana@@3P6ENK@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "int (__thiscall* isAttacking)(unsigned long)" (?isAttacking@@3P6EHK@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "unsigned long (__thiscall* getInventoryItem)(unsigned long,unsigned long *,unsigned int)" (?getInventoryItem@@3P6EKKPAKI@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj    Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "unsigned long (__thiscall* cancelFollow)(unsigned long)" (?cancelFollow@@3P6EKK@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "unsigned long (__thiscall* findItemInContainers)(unsigned long,unsigned long *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?findItemInContainers@@3P6EKKPAKII@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "unsigned long (__thiscall* talkChannel)(unsigned long,unsigned int,unsigned int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?talkChannel@@3P6EKKIIABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "void (__thiscall* useWith)(unsigned long,unsigned long *,unsigned long *,unsigned int)" (?useWith@@3P6EXKPAK0I@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "unsigned long (__thiscall* getAttackingCreature)(unsigned long,unsigned long *)" (?getAttackingCreature@@3P6EKKPAK@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "void (__thiscall* useItem)(unsigned long,unsigned long *)" (?useItem@@3P6EXKPAK@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "void (__thiscall* getTiles)(unsigned long,class std::list<unsigned long *,class std::allocator<unsigned long *> > *,unsigned int)" (?getTiles@@3P6EXKPAV?$list@PAKV?$allocator@PAK@std@@@std@@I@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "void (__thiscall* getTopCreature)(unsigned long *,unsigned long *)" (?getTopCreature@@3P6EXPAK0@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Release\Tibia Internal.dll    1
```

How should I use the .h and .cpp files correctly to don't get this error?

**EDIT:** as @AleXelton suggests I'm removing `#include "includes.h"` from functions.cpp and looks like this when compile:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "moduleBase" is undefined    Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  5   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "getMana" is undefined   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  6   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "_getMana" is undefined  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  6   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "isAttacking" is undefined   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  7   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "_isAttacking" is undefined  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  7   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "getInventoryItem" is undefined  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  8   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "_getInventoryItem" is undefined Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  8   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "cancelFollow" is undefined  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  9   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "_cancelFollow" is undefined Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  9   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "findItemInContainers" is undefined  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  10  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "_findItemInContainers" is undefined Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  10  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "talkChannel" is undefined   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  11  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "_talkChannel" is undefined  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  11  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "useWith" is undefined   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  12  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "_useWith" is undefined  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  12  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "getAttackingCreature" is undefined  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  13  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "_getAttackingCreature" is undefined Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  13  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "useItem" is undefined   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  14  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "_useItem" is undefined  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  14  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "getTiles" is undefined  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  15  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "_getTiles" is undefined Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  15  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "getTopCreature" is undefined    Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  16  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "_getTopCreature" is undefined   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  16  
Error   C2065   'moduleBase': undeclared identifier Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  5   
Error   C2065   'getMana': undeclared identifier    Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  6   
Error   C2065   '_getMana': undeclared identifier   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  6   
Error   C2065   'moduleBase': undeclared identifier Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  6   
Error   C2065   'isAttacking': undeclared identifier    Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  7   
Error   C2065   '_isAttacking': undeclared identifier   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  7   
Error   C2065   'moduleBase': undeclared identifier Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  7   
Error   C2065   'getInventoryItem': undeclared identifier   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  8   
Error   C2065   '_getInventoryItem': undeclared identifier  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  8   
Error   C2065   'moduleBase': undeclared identifier Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  8   
Error   C2065   'cancelFollow': undeclared identifier   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  9   
Error   C2065   '_cancelFollow': undeclared identifier  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  9   
Error   C2065   'moduleBase': undeclared identifier Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  9   
Error   C2065   'findItemInContainers': undeclared identifier   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  10  
Error   C2065   '_findItemInContainers': undeclared identifier  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  10  
Error   C2065   'moduleBase': undeclared identifier Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  10  
Error   C2065   'talkChannel': undeclared identifier    Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  11  
Error   C2065   '_talkChannel': undeclared identifier   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  11  
Error   C2065   'moduleBase': undeclared identifier Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  11  
Error   C2065   'useWith': undeclared identifier    Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  12  
Error   C2065   '_useWith': undeclared identifier   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  12  
Error   C2065   'moduleBase': undeclared identifier Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  12  
Error   C2065   'getAttackingCreature': undeclared identifier   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  13  
Error   C2065   '_getAttackingCreature': undeclared identifier  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  13  
Error   C2065   'moduleBase': undeclared identifier Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  13  
Error   C2065   'useItem': undeclared identifier    Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  14  
Error   C2065   '_useItem': undeclared identifier   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  14  
Error   C2065   'moduleBase': undeclared identifier Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  14  
Error   C2065   'getTiles': undeclared identifier   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  15  
Error   C2065   '_getTiles': undeclared identifier  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  15  
Error   C2065   'moduleBase': undeclared identifier Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  15  
Error   C2065   'getTopCreature': undeclared identifier Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  16  
Error   C2065   '_getTopCreature': undeclared identifier    Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  16  
Error   C2065   'moduleBase': undeclared identifier Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.cpp  16
```

I added `#include functions.h` instead and I get the same first results:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Release\Tibia Internal.dll    1   
Error   LNK2005 "unsigned int moduleBase" (?moduleBase@@3IA) already defined in dllmain.obj Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "double (__thiscall* getMana)(unsigned long)" (?getMana@@3P6ENK@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "int (__thiscall* isAttacking)(unsigned long)" (?isAttacking@@3P6EHK@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "unsigned long (__thiscall* getInventoryItem)(unsigned long,unsigned long *,unsigned int)" (?getInventoryItem@@3P6EKKPAKI@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj    Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "unsigned long (__thiscall* cancelFollow)(unsigned long)" (?cancelFollow@@3P6EKK@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "unsigned long (__thiscall* findItemInContainers)(unsigned long,unsigned long *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?findItemInContainers@@3P6EKKPAKII@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "unsigned long (__thiscall* talkChannel)(unsigned long,unsigned int,unsigned int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?talkChannel@@3P6EKKIIABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj   Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "void (__thiscall* useWith)(unsigned long,unsigned long *,unsigned long *,unsigned int)" (?useWith@@3P6EXKPAK0I@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "unsigned long (__thiscall* getAttackingCreature)(unsigned long,unsigned long *)" (?getAttackingCreature@@3P6EKKPAK@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj  Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "void (__thiscall* useItem)(unsigned long,unsigned long *)" (?useItem@@3P6EXKPAK@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "void (__thiscall* getTiles)(unsigned long,class std::list<unsigned long *,class std::allocator<unsigned long *> > *,unsigned int)" (?getTiles@@3P6EXKPAV?$list@PAKV?$allocator@PAK@std@@@std@@I@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "void (__thiscall* getTopCreature)(unsigned long *,unsigned long *)" (?getTopCreature@@3P6EXPAK0@ZA) already defined in dllmain.obj Tibia Internal  C:\Users\Adrian\Documents\cracking\Tibia Internal\Tibia Internal\functions.obj  1
```

Comment: Please remove #include "includes.h" from function.cpp, including "includes.h" is repeated on function's header and cpp files.

Comment: I just tested and edited question with results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`functions.h` declares a bunch of global variables.  Any `.cpp` file that includes `functions.h` (ie, by including `includes.h`) will get *its own copy* of those variables.  Hence, the "already defined" errors when the linker tries to bring the compiled units together into the final executable.

If your goal is to share those variables between `.cpp` files, you need to *declare* the variables as `extern` in `functions.h` file, and then *define* the actual variables in `functions.cpp`, eg:

Functions.h

```
#pragma once
#include "includes.h"

void InitFunctions();

extern uintptr_t moduleBase;

// getMana
typedef double(__thiscall* _getMana)(DWORD localplayer);
extern _getMana getMana;
// isAttacking
typedef int(__thiscall* _isAttacking)(DWORD localplayer);
extern _isAttacking isAttacking;
// getInventoryItem
typedef DWORD(__thiscall* _getInventoryItem)(DWORD localplayer, DWORD* buffer, uintptr_t index);
extern _getInventoryItem getInventoryItem;
// cancelFollow
typedef DWORD(__thiscall* _cancelFollow)(DWORD localplayer);
extern _cancelFollow cancelFollow;
// findItemInContainers
typedef DWORD(__thiscall* _findItemInContainers)(DWORD localplayer, DWORD* buffer, uintptr_t id, uintptr_t type);
extern _findItemInContainers findItemInContainers;
// talkChannel
typedef DWORD(__thiscall* _talkChannel)(DWORD localplayer, uintptr_t mode, uintptr_t channelId, const std::string& message);
extern _talkChannel talkChannel;
// useWith
typedef void(__thiscall* _useWith)(DWORD localplayer, DWORD* item, DWORD* toThing, uintptr_t subType);
extern _useWith useWith;
// getAttackingCreature
typedef DWORD(__thiscall* _getAttackingCreature)(DWORD localplayer, DWORD* buffer);
extern _getAttackingCreature getAttackingCreature;
// useItem    
typedef void(__thiscall* _useItem)(DWORD localplayer, DWORD* item);
extern _useItem useItem;
// get tiles
typedef void(__thiscall* _getTiles)(DWORD map, TileList* buffer, uintptr_t floor);
extern _getTiles getTiles;
// getTopCreature
typedef void(__thiscall* _getTopCreature)(TilePtr tile, DWORD* buffer);
extern _getTopCreature getTopCreature;
```

functions.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "functions.h"

uintptr_t moduleBase;
_getMana getMana;
_isAttacking isAttacking;
_getInventoryItem getInventoryItem;
_cancelFollow cancelFollow;
_findItemInContainers findItemInContainers;
_talkChannel talkChannel;
_useWith useWith;
_getAttackingCreature getAttackingCreature;
_useItem useItem;
_getTiles getTiles;
_getTopCreature getTopCreature;

void InitFunctions(){
    // get base address
    moduleBase = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(L"NewHorizon_DirectX.exe");
    getMana = (_getMana)(moduleBase + 0x5A830);
    isAttacking = (_isAttacking)(moduleBase + 0x734A0);
    getInventoryItem = (_getInventoryItem)(moduleBase + 0x949C0);
    cancelFollow = (_cancelFollow)(moduleBase + 0x73420);
    findItemInContainers = (_findItemInContainers)(moduleBase + 0x78710);
    talkChannel = (_talkChannel)(moduleBase + 0x79340);
    useWith = (_useWith)(moduleBase + 0x78220);
    getAttackingCreature = (_getAttackingCreature)(moduleBase + 0x93F90);
    useItem = (_useItem)(moduleBase + 0x77E60);
    getTiles = (_getTiles)(moduleBase + 0x142860);
    getTopCreature = (_getTopCreature)(moduleBase + 0x192BC0);
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer. Understood everything at first read and the code worked: ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========. Thank you @Remy